Question about proof in Lemma 10.9 in "Lectures on von Neumann algebras"
I am trying to understand the proof of Lemma 10.9 in the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" by Stratila and Zsido. More specifically, I am trying to understand the equality boxed below.



It seems like we must justify
$$s(\omega'_{\xi_1, \xi_0})= (v')^*v'.$$
I can see that $$s(\omega_{\xi_1}, \xi_0') \le (v')^*v'$$
but the other inequality is not clear to me.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Recall that $s(\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0})$ satisfies $R_{s(\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0})}\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0} = \omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0}$. That is, $(x’s(\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0})\xi_1|\xi_0) = (x’\xi_1|\xi_0)$ for all $x’ \in \mathcal{M}’$. Equivalently, $(s(\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0})\xi_1|x’\xi_0) = (\xi_1|x’\xi_0)$ for all $x’ \in \mathcal{M}’$. Since $\xi_0$ is separating for $\mathcal{M}$, it is cyclic for $\mathcal{M}’$, whence $s(\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0})\xi_1 = \xi_1$. Now, $s(\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0})$ is a projection in $\mathcal{M}’$ that sends $\xi_1$ to itself, so $s(\omega’_{\xi_1, \xi_0})$ majorizes the projection onto $[\mathcal{M}\xi_1]$, which is precisely $(v’)^\ast v’$.

Splendid answer. Thanks.
